# Nativebase Icons getImageSource

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

Since [Nativebase](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#icon-def-headref%20Nativebase) uses [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons%20react-native-vector-icons), is it possible to `getImageSource` from Nativebase/`Icon` wrapper without having to install/link vector icons separately?

I need to pass the image source to Wix's [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage%20react-native-navigation) `startTabBasedApp` method, e.g:

```
# Using Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

Promise.all([
    Icon.getImageSource(Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'md-map' : 'ios-map', 30),
    Icon.getImageSource(Platform.OS === 'android' ?  'md-share-alt' : 'ios-share', 30),
    Icon.getImageSource(Platform.OS === 'android' ?  'md-menu' : 'ios-menu', 30)
  ]).then(sources => {
    Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
      tabs: [
        {
          screen: "myapp.Explore",
          label: "Explore",
          title: "Explore",
          icon: sources[0]
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NativeBase Icon uses React Native Vector Icons (RNVI)
If you can use RNVI's Icon.getImageSource in wix's react-native-navigation, then you can also use NativeBase's Icon for same

Check [Docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#icon-def-headref) for same